# Finding this line integral, on a sphere radius $a$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

$$
c \equiv
\left\lbrace\left(x,y,z\right)\quad |\quad x^{2} + y^{2} + z^{2} = a^{2}\,,\quad
             x + y + z = 0\right\rbrace
$$

$$
\mbox{Find}\quad \int_{c}x^2
$$

This is a line integral.
$c$ is definitely some kind of circle/elipse , the intersection of these two surfaces.

I know that this can be solved using the symmetric properties of a sphere in relation to all three axis, that's the shortest way to solve this. But I want to know if it is solvable like this, because my professor said the this is the second route.

He wrote that plugging in the second in the first you get:
$$
\left(x + \frac{y}{2}\right)^{2} + \frac{3y^{2}}{4} = \frac{a^{2}}{2}
$$
and then he said to right $x,y,z$ in relation to $\varphi$: $x = x\left(\varphi\right) , y = y\left(\varphi\right), z = z\left(\varphi\right)$.
Is it possible to do it like this ?. Does this make sense:
$$
x + \frac{y}{2} = \frac{a}{\sqrt{2}}\cos\left(\varphi\right)\,,\ \frac{\sqrt{3}y}{2} = \frac{a}{\sqrt{2}}\,\sin\left(\varphi\right)
$$

$$
\mbox{or}\quad
\left\lbrace\begin{array}{rcl}
 \displaystyle{x\left(\varphi\right)} & = &\displaystyle{\frac{a}{2}\cos\left(\varphi\right) -
\frac{a}{\sqrt{6}}\sin\left(\varphi\right)}
\\[1mm]
 \displaystyle{y(\varphi)} & = &
 \displaystyle{\frac{2a}{\sqrt{6}}\,\sin\left(\varphi\right)}
 \\[1mm]
 \displaystyle{z} & = & \displaystyle{z\left(x\left(\varphi\right),y\left(\varphi\right)\right)}
 \\[2mm]
 && \displaystyle{0 < \varphi < 2\pi}
\end{array}\right.
$$

$$
\int_{0}^{2\pi}x^{2}\left(\varphi\right)\sqrt{\,x'^{2}\left(\varphi\right) + y'^{2}\left(\varphi\right) + z'^{2}\left(\varphi\right)\,}
\,\,\mathrm{d}\varphi
$$

Is this correct ?

Comment: To begin with, you’ve gotten the substitution wrong. The second term should be $\frac34y^2$, not $\left(\frac34y\right)^2$.

Comment: thats not whats important here, its a small detail, i took into what you say into consideration with these substitutions.

Comment: There doesn’t appear to be anything extraordinary going on here. You’re finding a parametrization for the curve by first examining its projection onto the $xy$-plane. This may not be the best way to solve this problem, though, since the expression under the radical looks like it’ll be fairly messy. The answer below gives a better approach—essentially transforming to a coordinate system in which the $uv$-plane is the plane $x+y+z=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to use an isometry to "straigthen" things up. The matrix
$$\begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \\-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \\ 0 & \frac{2}{\sqrt{6}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\end{pmatrix}$$
is orthogonal, hence we may set $\frac{x-y}{\sqrt{2}}=u,\frac{-x-y+2z}{\sqrt{6}}=v,\frac{x+y+z}{\sqrt{3}}=w$ and the original problem turns into computing
$$ I=\int_c \left(\frac{3\sqrt{2} u-\sqrt{6} v+2\sqrt{3} w}{6}\right)^2\,d\mu $$
over the curve given by $u^2+v^2+w^2=a^2$ and $w=0$.

By setting $u=a\sin\theta, v=a\cos\theta$ we get:

> $$ I = \frac{a^3}{36} \int_{0}^{2\pi}\left( 3\sqrt{2}\sin\theta-\sqrt{6}\cos\theta\right)^2\,d\theta = \color{red}{\frac{2\pi a^3}{3}}.$$

Your method is just a minor variation of mine, so it ultimately works, but obviously the slickest method is to exploit the $(x,y,z)\mapsto(y,z,x)$ symmetry to state:

$$ \int_{c} x^2\,d\mu = \frac{1}{3}\int_{c}(x^2+y^2+z^2)\,d\mu = \frac{a^2}{3}\cdot \mu(c) $$
and recover the previous result in a single line.

Comment: I completely agree with this. I am interested though, the method I state above, is it correct, or possible, no matter how difficult?I ask because it is related to something I wish to use with other problems. Does it seem correct?

Comment: @BozoVulicevic: my last addendum answers your question, I hope.